# Calculate P75/P90 value with given P50 and STD in Python

Tags: python, std, p-value

I just started with my first steps in Python and I´d like to calculate from a yield estimation from a Wind Park (P50) and a given overall measurement uncertainty (std) the P75 and P90 value, with an underlying normal distribution.

I tried for example:

```
P50 = 35556325 #kWh p.a.
std = 0.13

s = np.random.normal(P50, std, 0)
```

but I don´t know how to call then a certain P-value in the distribution.

Is there an easy way to get fast the P75-value out of this? Or a different function?

Certainly this is not a big thing, but I´m somehow stuck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: ```
from scipy.stats import norm

mean = 35556325 #P50
std = 0.12 * mean

P75 = norm.ppf((1-0.75), mean, std)
```